# What's a good temporary storage & transport format for Python?

Tags: python, file-io, storage

I'm writing a script in Python that will spit out some data organized as a list of dicts:

```
[{'name': 'first_thing', 'color': 'blue', 'flavour': 'watermelon' },
 {'name': 'second_thing', 'color': 'red' },
 {'name': 'third_thing', 'color': 'blue', 'size': 'huge!' }]
```

I am trying to decide on a way to store this data in a file. My considerations:

1. I'd like it to be as easy to read as to write, so I can load the data back into a script and manipulate it further.
2. I'd like it to be a non-python-specific format. Maybe later I'll want to use this data in PHP or something, who knows?
3. I'd like it to be a format to which it is easy to append more data. If my file has a list with 1000 of my little dict items in it, I do not want to load all 1000 into memory just to add one more item to the end.

My first try was to use Pickle, which meets the easy criteria, but it's Python-dependent and i'd have to unpickle, append, then repickle.

Other formats I've thought of that seem feasible (with my objections):

- JSON (appending is going to be annoying, maybe)
- Shelve (python specific)
- CSV (like duct tape, not so classy, but it would probably work)
- Some kind of light database like sqlite (maybe getting too fancy here)

Anybody have arguments for any of these or another format?

Comment: have you looked at XML? you can create your own schema and use that as a standard for all programs using the data you output. Although XML is quite large it's great for cross language / platform stuff.

Comment: I hadn't considered XML. It's certainly a cross-platform format. Is there a way to write it as easily as, say, pickle.dump()?

Comment: I've never tried writing XML in python, but it should definatly have a library or two for it, It won't be as easy as pickle however, and probably a bit more fiddly than CSV, try http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonXml for a good start.

Comment: Was just reminded of this question... many years later, with a bit more experience under my belt, I might advise myself to use jsonl (http://jsonlines.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your need to append data later, [YAML](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) might be the format you're looking for. It's designed explicitly to support appended data elements ala a log file, json  is deliberately a proper subset of the language, and it has some useful meta markup designed for powerful cross-language serialization of custom classes.

Comment: Ah. Separate documents can make up a stream. Cross-platform. Easy. Bingo.

Comment: aside from separate documents, I've found one long doc that's a multi-line list (each entry starting with '-') can also be appended to pretty easily, as long as the per entry data stays on one line , which it has options for.

Answer (score 2):

Pickle should work fine.
Store the dicts directly (not in a list) to making appending easier:

```
>>> from pickle import dump, load
>>> f = open('stor.bin', 'w')
>>> dump(dict(a=1), f)
>>> dump(dict(b=2), f)
>>> dump(dict(c=3), f)
>>> f.close()
```

In subsequent sessions, append another dump() directly to the end of the file:

```
>>> f = open('store.bin', 'a')
>>> dump(dict(d=4), f)
>>> f.close()
```

To read, just perform load() repeatedly until you hit the end of the file:

```
>>> f = open('stor.bin', 'r')
>>> load(f)
{'a': 1}
>>> load(f)
{'b': 2}
>>> load(f)
{'c': 3}
>>> load(f)
{'d': 4}
>>> load(f)

Traceback (most recent call last):
   ...
EOFError
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was suggesting you do with JSON.

Comment: No need to get testy. The difference is, as the docs say: "Unlike pickle and marshal, JSON is not a framed protocol so trying to serialize more objects with repeated calls to dump() and the same fp will result in an invalid JSON file."

Comment: @benauthor, I was remember the quote but backwards. I thought it said that marshal wasn't framed like JSON and pickle. my bad. Technically, it seems to me that you could do this with JSON since it is self-delimiting but apparently the api doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1):

For most of the cases, I think JSON should be your best bet.

Use simplejson to convert your *list* of dict to JSON, that will be as simple as:

```
import simplejson as json
my_list = [{'name': 'first_thing', 'color': 'blue', 'flavour': 'watermelon'}, {'name': 'second_thing','color': 'red' }, {'name': 'third_thing', 'color': 'blue', 'size': 'huge!'}]
output = json.dumps(my_list, ident=4)
```

The result JSON will be:

```
[
    {
        "color": "blue",
        "flavour": "watermelon",
        "name": "first_thing"
    },
    {
        "color": "red",
        "name": "second_thing"
    },
    {
        "color": "blue",
        "name": "third_thing",
        "size": "huge!"
    }
]
```

Now, this JSON is a perfectly a valid JSON string.

It's a [JSON array](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/spry/samples/data_region/JSONDataSetSample.html#Example2). So I don't think you need to do a hack to remove "[" and "]". Since you are passing a python list to simplejson, you *will* get a JSON list back.

Comment: Yeah but when I want to add more items to the same file tomorrow... maybe i'm being thick but wouldn't I have to do some pretty raw string manipulation, like seek backward in the file and chop off the closing ] and so forth? Else how do new items get inside the containing list?

Comment: decode json to python list, add element to list and encode it again.

Comment: right, but that's what I'm trying to avoid. i haven't done performance testing but i feel like loading 1000 items from a file to add number 1001 and write back to a file would be slower than a solution that would let me just write number 1001 to the end of the file directly.

Answer (score 0):

From your example data snippet, it sure looks like your data fits a tabular format better than the more complex formats.  If the keys of your dicts are known before-hand, and used in every entry, I think CSV is the right choice.  Python also has a csv module to make that easier.

Comment: I guess I'm a little lazy and would prefer not have to keep track of all the keys... my real data is actually much messier than my example. Not insurmountable, and I may end up doing that, but still not totally sold.

Comment: Just how much messier, and in what kinds of ways?  Can you flesh out your description of your data a bit more?

Comment: There'll be a fixed list of 15 or so fields, and any given item will have anywhere from two to all of them.

Comment: Also, your lego nameplates are awesome! (looked at your profile) I'm thinking xmas gifts...

Comment: Regarding the nameplates, thanks!  :)   As for your data, that doesn't sound all that messy... is there _any_ chance that some manager-type might want access to this data?  They tend to love Excel, and .csv would work for that use-case whereas the others won't.